# Ubuntu 18.04.3 netboot PXE fresh installed boots up with Ethernet not managed by Network Manager

Tags: network-interface, networkmanager, pxe, initrd, netboot

I'm trying to set up a **PXE** server to deliver Linux image for end user workstation in my company.

I've finally made it to set up `dnsmasq` and `nfs-kernel-server` so now I can get the images via network and start the installer.

*The problem is*: all installer steps runs well but when I get into my fresh installed OS the Ethernet connection appears as "**unmanaged**" by Network Manager.

Looking for an answer to it on the web I've realized there's a workaround that solves the issue.

*My big doubt is*: Is there a way to preset an post-install config file (`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`) inside ISO's folder to prevent this behavior?

**NOTE**: installing the same ISO from a flash drive prevents the problem, but I don't understand this behavior because both PXE server and flash drive are using same `initrd` and `vmlinuz` files.

Could anyone please give me a hand? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a ISO editor solved the problem.